# Speech vs Music classification

Tags: reference-request, pattern-recognition

I want to determine which parts of an audio file contain speech respectively music.

I hope someone has a made something like this or can tell me where to start. Can you please suggest some method or tutorial for doing the same?

Comment: There are a lot of papers/documentation online, just search for "[music speech discrimination](https://www.google.it/search?q=speech+music+discrimination)", or take a look at this: "[Speech and Music Classification and Separation: A Review](http://repository.ksu.edu.sa/jspui/bitstream/123456789/244/1/Speech%20and%20Music%20Classification%20and%20Separation:%20A%20Review.pdf)"

Comment: @Kaveh: “If you are looking for algorithms then the question might be OK here”: Please be careful to make a general statement like that.  I think that from OP’s viewpoint, he or she is _obviously_ looking for algorithms (which classify audio to speech and music), so according to what you said, “the question might be OK here.”  But the issue with this question is that the problem to solve is not well-defined from the TCS point of view: “speech” and “music” are just what human interpret a sound as, and their meanings cannot be defined mathematically without referring to human.  (more)

Comment: (cont’d) Exploring the characteristic differences of what human interprets as speech and what human interprets as music is not in the scope of TCS, and this is the main point of the question.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: IMO the difference between a BIG "$2^n$" and a small  "$n^k$"  is also a "human interpretation" :-)

Comment: @Vor: No.  The difference between $2^n$ and $n^k$ is well-defined in mathematical sense.  Interpreting this difference as important is a human interpretation, but the interpretation does not affect the definition of, say, P.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: ... I'm just kidding :-). However I think that a good and widely accepted math model of what is speech and what is music can be found (and indeed there is a lot of work on the subject). Once you have fixed the model then you enter the "machine learning - machine recognition" domains that are pretty close to TCS.

Comment: @Vor: Your joke does not make sense to me, but that point aside, if there is a good mathematical model of what is speech and what is music, then as you said, the problem becomes one in TCS once you fix the model, possibly a very interesting one.  The current question lacks the model, which is the problem, because TCS cannot decide a way to model the human cognition.

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate technique is machine learning. Some keywords you could search for are "music speech discrimination", and you could look at [this survey](http://repository.ksu.edu.sa/jspui/bitstream/123456789/244/1/Speech%20and%20Music%20Classification%20and%20Separation%3a%20A%20Review.pdf). (These pointers came from Vor's comment.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have many data ( large number of audio pieces with human labels), I would suggest you try Deep Convolutional Neural Networks. But I think there should be a much more direct way than that, since I believe the spectrum could be a very good feature for discriminate decisions.

Comment: Do you have any evidence why those networks can be expected to work well for this problem?

Comment: @Raphael, I think those deep networks learn very good feature representation of audio signals -- see this example https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.154.380%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=wBISUY8whMfRAf3wgKgI&usg=AFQjCNEHHjJHQEQCwuXW5oOfO0nA--dSlg&bvm=bv.41934586,d.dmg&cad=rja. Of course, theories to explain why these neural networks work well are still within the scope of active research.